# Dreamweaver equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux

I am looking for an equivalent software to Dreamweaver in Linux.

Comment: I will need to program, PHP, Ruby, CSS 2/3, JS, ASP, which are all supported my Dreamweaver.  Ofcourse, I will require ASP installation on Linux, thats different

Comment: Stackoverflow should permit two accepted answers, as in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an exact match but it is based out of Eclipse which means super cross platform funky java love.

http://www.aptana.com/

Aptana Studio is actually what I replaced Dreamweaver with since Adobe bought Macromedia, I use it on Windows and Linux without trouble. But for the suggestion you will also get my 2 cents about Wysiwtf... it is almost never what you get. Some of the best code I have ever done in my life was done in SciTE (also available in Linux), it supports multiple coding languages and offers enough features to be useful without becoming bloated.

Comment: Now http://www.aptana.com

Answer (score 2):

If you want something reasonably non-technical, then perhaps [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/)?

Or, if you want more technical stuff, then you probably want [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Another mention [bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what desktop environment you use I can recommend [Quanta+](http://quanta.kdewebdev.org/) to you. It's part of the KDE SC but can also be used in other DEs.

You could also use [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/), it seems to be nice as well. Didn't test this one though.

Answer (score 0):

I've also researched this for myself, and the answer is that, in my opinion, there is nothing comparable.

Most people choose Dreamweaver for its WYSIWYG (as good as it can be with HTML), and the ease of use. If you're looking for database connectivity, PHP debugging and the like, then Elipse beats Dreamweaver by a lot, but chance is the original poster is looking for the ease-of-use, so neither Bluefish nor Eclipse is going to satisfy him.