# Open source web design toolsets

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for recommendations on an open source toolset for WYSIWYG HTML/CSS design.  What you have you found to be valuable in your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I briefly used [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) while in college, which has similar features to Dreamweaver.

Wikipedia has a good list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors).

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**

- Web Applications - Microsoft Visual
  Web Developer Express 2010 (**Not Open Source**, but powerful for large applications)
- Web-Sites and Microsites - Intype +
  FileZilla (**Not Open Source**, but faster alternatives)
- Notepad++ is a quick alternative too,
  that has various plugins (like FTP, [**Open Source**])

**Mac**

- TextMate & Coda (I hear these are cool and sleak)

Comment: +1 for VWD Express even thought it is not open source. It is certainly very good, and free.

Comment: I doubt that is open source...

Comment: add `gedit` for Linux users...

Answer (score 1):

[Dreamweaver equivalent for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719494/dreamweaver-equivalent-for-linux/2719520#2719520)

asked a similar question and my answer is still the same, aptana is cross platform. Also please note the concept that WSYWIG is not generally what you get, you may also want to look into jsfiddle.net as it is a great tool for testing concepts in a functional environment.